# Using multiple MongoDB databases in a spring boot application

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a spring boot application where i am using MongoRepository to connect to backend.

**application.properties** :

```
#Mongo
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://XXXXXX:XXXXXXX@dev0.abcdre.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
spring.data.mongodb.database=db1
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```

**my repository interface** :

```
public interface RDDRepository extends MongoRepository<RDDModel , ObjectId> {
    public List<RDDModel > findAll();
}
```

**Model :** // here db_latest is the collection name inside db1 database.

```
@Document(collection = "db_latest")
public class RDDModel {

some getter and setters 
}
```

And I am calling using this interface for my service.

Now I have a requirement where I need to findAll() from DB2 database related collection.

What is the best way that I can choose to call the second database from a spring boot project.

Can you please mention different ways -

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-configure-multiple-mongodb-connectors-in-spring-boot-669f36fe9d3e

Comment: DB2 is an IBM product and unrelated to MongoDB.  Please clarify.

Comment: @barrypicker I just took the name as an example. its not a product. you can take some other name like -"ADB2"